# How to generate the entity in Symfony 3.4 using command?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have created the ORM file for my table `remuneration`. I already, created the Form type file for the same ORM file. I have used to generate the entity "ClientRemuneration" using this command:
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/ClientRemuneration`
But, it not working and throw this error:

> Class "DatumGraph\Spade\MasterBundle\Entity\ClientRemuneration" is not
>   a valid entity or mapped super class".

Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Are you using Symfony Flex?

Comment: Yes. I have used the Symfony flex.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're missing the `@ORM\Entity` annotation on your class, Doctrine throws the exception you mention.
Take a look to the official doctrine symfony doc for more informations: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Define the real entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ClientRemuneration extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

Define the super-class as follows:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

**Generate entities (getters and setters):**
If you are using symfony app version **> 4.0**, then you should use `bin/console make:entity --regenerate` to generate entities.
Else, you should use `bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` command.

**Generate Entity(The php class):**
If you are using symfony app version **> 4.0**, then you should use `bin/console make:entity` to generate the entity.
Else, you should use `bin/console doctrine:generate:èntity` command.